# Symfony 3 MySQL driver 'could not find driver'

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, pdo, doctrine-orm

I actualy got some difficulties with Symfony 3 and PDO driver.

It's my first project with Symfony 3 (I used Symfony 2 before that), and when I want to use Doctrine or FOSUserBundle I got this error :

> ## could not find driver
>
> **500** Internal
>   Server Error - PDOException

I check what was wrong and I found it's was an error throw by :
[/path-to-project/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOMySql](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOMySql/Driver.php)

It's a simple PDOException throw when the PDO class can't access to the Database server.
**BUT** I can execute this code without problem 
with a "$> php test.php"

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:dbname=Accounting;host=127.0.0.1","<user>", "<secret>");
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM Accounting.fos_user;';
echo count($pdo->query($sql));
```

And this error is throw by the same code, execute by Symfony 3 (By Doctrine and tested in a simple Controller).

---

Here are my parameters :

```
# app/config/parameters.yml
parameters:
    database_driver: pdo_mysql
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: 3306
    database_name: Accounting
    database_user: <user>
    database_password: <secret>

# app/config/config.yml
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   "%database_driver%"
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
        #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
        #     e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
        #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
        #   3. Uncomment next line:
        #     path:     "%database_path%"

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: UserBundle\Entity\User
```

**EDIT** 29/03/2016

OS Configuration : Ubuntu 14-04 on a VM

Comment: You have `pdo_mysql` enabled in `cli/php.ini` but not in `fpm/php.ini`, that's why in command line working, but not in web browser. You need to add this line to php.ini: `extension=pdo_mysql.so`

Comment: I'm using an Ubuntu, and the folder /etc/php5/fpm doesn't exist. Maybe should I install a package/plugin for php?
I tried to `cp -r /etc/php5/cli /etc/php5/fpm` but the problem still remain.

~ty for your contribution

Comment: Sorry I mean in cgi not cli. Have you the extension enabled in php5/cli/php.ini?

Comment: pdo.so and pdo_mysql, yes in cli. I going to check the cgi folder when I'm back.

Comment: in both cli/conf.d and cgi/conf.d are same for pdo.so and pdo_mysql.so ~ty for your contribution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer to my own question. This problem happen because I try to use symfony with mysql pdo driver on a **container** (form a virtualisation). When I use the same setup on a **real VM** (= fully virtualize virtual machine) It's work correctly. Driver are found and we can create pdo in a Symfony 3 project.

***Tested the 10/04/2016***

Ty malcolm for the helping, I learn somethings thanks to you :)

Regards, Dykoine